# Multimedia keys are not working with my HP Probook 4540s

Tags: keyboard, hp, function-keys

I have HP Probook 4540S. 
My multimedia keys such as Wifi on/off & brightness control keys doesn't work with Ubuntu 13.04. (Keys function well with Ubuntu 12.04)

Both are working well in Windows.
Please give me a workaround..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m using hp4540s and I’ve stumled over this too.
In Ubuntu 13.04 the kernel is 3.8.x-xx
It supports WIFI out of the box but does not support Fn+brightness. 
If you go back to Ubuntu 12.04 with kernlel 3.2.x-xx you will have Fn-functions but you will not have WIFI.
Workaround 1: 
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-fix-function-keys-fn-issue-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-10-04lucid.html
Follow the instructions BUT be sure to correct the NECESSARY line:  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
After correction it should look as GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"
Grub update needed.
You’ll get you Fn+brightness keys working. BUT after each reboot  the brightness will return to maximum.
Workaround 2:
I have decided to go back to 12.04 (actually linux mint 13 Maya).
No Fn+brightness problems  and the WIFI problem was perfectly solved with a new kernel 3.6.3. installation.
http://compizomania.blogspot.com/2012/10/linux-kernel-363-ubuntu-12101204linux.html
The tutorial is in Russian but it is understandable.
Workaround 3: (only my invention  - not tested though)
Try downgrading kernel of your Ubuntu 13.04  from 3.8.x-xx to kernel 3.6.3